# Use 'ghost element' to vertically align an inline-block element of width 100% within its container

Tags: css, alignment, vertical-alignment

[this article](https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) mentions a technique of vertically centering an element in css using a 'ghost element'.

```
/* This parent can be any width and height */
.block {
  text-align: center;

  /* May want to do this if there is risk the container may be narrower than the element inside */
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* The ghost, nudged to maintain perfect centering */
.block:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}

/* The element to be centered, can also be of any width and height */ 
.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 300px;
}
```

[codepen here.](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/gsodI)

It doesn't work, however, when the element to be centered has `width:100%`, becuse the element gets pushed onto a new line. How you adapt the solution in order to work in this case? I need a solution with good browser support including IE9+

Comment: [**CCS-Trick : A Compete Guide to Centering**](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Comment: There is a reason why I need this solution to work in particular. Also, I believe the solution proposed in your link for "both horizontally and vertically for element of unknown height and width" is non-ideal in that it [can cause elements to become blurred due to sub-pixel rendering](http://martinkool.com/post/27618832225/beware-of-half-pixels-in-css)

Comment: Swings and roundabouts...you pay's your money, you takes your choice. Good luck.

Comment: Are you using :before instead of ::before, or is that just a typo in the question?

Comment: Ah! I was doing that, but it works even when you only use one colon.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I was suffering from the "spacing between empty inline-block elements problem". There are a few ways to fix this, I fixed it by commenting out the whitespace between elements in the HTML.
[Here is a working plunker](http://bit.ly/1feQ5SM)